# StructureMap not finding generic Types when used with scan.TheCallingAssembly

Tags: c#, .net, structuremap

I have an Application-Assembly, which contains an amount of generic IMapper Interfaces. Each implementation has said Types and two methods to map the objects in each direction.
Using AutoMapper, I went ahead using their documentation and created an IocRegistry-Class in said Application-Assembly, which should register all Types:

```
public class IocRegistry : Registry
{
    public IocRegistry()
    {
        Scan(
            scan =>
            {
                scan.TheCallingAssembly(); // Scan this assembly
                scan.WithDefaultConventions();
                scan.AddAllTypesOf(typeof(IMapper<,>));
            });
    }
}
```

And if I use the "WhatDidIScan"-method, I can see the configuration:

> ### IocRegistry Scanner #1 Assemblies
>
> - Mmu.Ddws.Application, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
>
> ### Conventions
>
> - Default I[Name]/[Name] registration convention
> - Find and register all types implementing Mmu.Ddws.Application.Common.Mapping.IMapper`2

Yet, as soon as I try to get an instance of such a Mapper, I get the error it didn't find it.

Interesting enough, if I'm registerering the Interfaces on my WebServices-Assembly, which is the starting point, via:

```
internal static class IocInitialization
{
    internal static IServiceProvider InitializeIoc(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var container = new Container();

        container.Configure(
            config =>
            {
                config.Scan(
                    scan =>
                    {
                        scan.AssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory();
                        scan.LookForRegistries();
                        scan.WithDefaultConventions();
                        scan.AddAllTypesOf(typeof(IMapper<,>));
                    });

                config.Populate(services);
            });

        Debug.WriteLine(container.WhatDidIScan());
        var result = container.GetInstance<IServiceProvider>();
        return result;
    }
}
```

I get exactly the same convention:

> ### Conventions
>
> - StructureMap.Graph.FindRegistriesScanner
> - Default I[Name]/[Name] registration convention
> - Find and register all types implementing Mmu.Ddws.Application.Common.Mapping.IMapper`2

And yet, this way it works. I have the Interface and the Implementations in the Application-Assembly, therefore the most discussions resolving around Interfaces in different Assemblies, doesn't seem to fit here. So my best bet would be, that scanning the calling Assembly is kinda wrong, but I couldn't find any remarks regarding this?

Comment: I'm really surprised this doesn't have an answer yet

Answer (score 0):

See this for details and an example on type scanning with open generic types: http://structuremap.github.io/generics/

Comment: Not sure if I missunderstood you, but the scanning works generelly, it just seems to be a difference if I use AssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory or TheCallingAssembly. Also the scanned output of both is the same, so this can't be a configuration reason, no?